# SQL count per day and add together all following days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a SQL query to count users per day and add the result together. I'm stuck because I don't know how to dynamically add the results together.

Table:

```
UserId | CreateDate
-------+----------------------------
  1    | 2016-06-23 13:59:24.0000000
  2    | 2016-06-23 15:59:24.0000000
  3    | 2016-06-24 05:59:24.0000000
  ...
```

I have following query to count the registrations per day.

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(date, u.CreateDate) as [Date], Count(UserId) as [Count] 
FROM 
    User as u
GROUP BY 
    CONVERT(date, u.CreateDate)
ORDER BY
    [Date]
```

I have no idea how to add up the results. I hope that SQL Server 2008 R2 has a built-in function for my case. Or do I need to create temp tables?

Assuming Day 1 has 2 registrations and Day 2 has 1 registration and Day 3 has 4 registrations, I would like to receive a result like this:

```
2016-06-23 | 2
2016-06-24 | 2 + 1 = 3
2016-06-25 | 3 + 4 = 7
```

I would need a dynamic solution because the query will have another restriction by date => Where CreateDate bewteen x and y.

Thanks
Ruedi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sum` window function to get the running total.

```
select [Date],sum([Count]) over(order by [Date]) 
from (SELECT CONVERT(date, u.CreateDate) as [Date], Count(UserId) as [Count] 
      FROM User as u
      GROUP BY CONVERT(date, u.CreateDate)
      ) x
order by 1
```

Add a `where` clause to filter for a specific date range in the inner query.

Comment: Should be `SELECT TOP n CONVERT(date, u.CreateDate) as [Date], ...`

Comment: This is working, I already knew Sum but I think over is doing the magic here. Over is new to me I have to take a deeper look on this function. Thank you. I will flag your answer as solution as soon I'm able to do it. You were too fast :)

Answer (score 0):

with redshift database

```sql
select [Date],sum([Count]) over(order by [Date] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
from (SELECT CONVERT(date, u.CreateDate) as [Date], Count(UserId) as [Count] 
      FROM User as u
      GROUP BY CONVERT(date, u.CreateDate)
      ) x
order by 1
```

Comment: Can you please include in your answer the logic or how does this code work?